# How to start a fragment from an xml resource

Tags: android

I have a TabLayout Activity, and for one of the tabs (case 3) i want to use a `PreferenceFragment` for a settings page. In case 3 below i've declared the fragment, but how do I start it?

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = null;
    switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
        case 1: {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find, container, false);
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            SettingsFragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            // what goes here?
            break;
        }
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

full code:

```
public class Find extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find);


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
        tab1.setCustomView(R.layout.icon_view);
        tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.profile);

        TabLayout.Tab tab2 = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
        tab2.setCustomView(R.layout.icon_view);
        tab2.setIcon(R.drawable.logo_a);

        TabLayout.Tab tab3 = tabLayout.getTabAt(2);
        tab3.setCustomView(R.layout.icon_view);
        tab3.setIcon(R.drawable.settings);

    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                // Load the preferences from an XML resource
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = null;
            switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
                case 1: {
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find, container, false);
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    SettingsFragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                    // what goes here?
                    break;
                }
            }

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }
```

Comment: have you used any adapter? if yes please post your adapter class

Comment: Added full code in edit.

Comment: See my answer. Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Getting this error with your code: https://i.imgur.com/H7zPpHt.png any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Separate `SettingsFragment`  from `PlaceholderFragment`
2. Update SectionsPagerAdapter's `getItem()` method to show `SettingsFragment` for `3rd` TAB.
3. Remove `case 3` from `onCreateView()`.

**Try this:**

```
public class Find extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find);


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
        tab1.setCustomView(R.layout.icon_view);
        tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.profile);

        TabLayout.Tab tab2 = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
        tab2.setCustomView(R.layout.icon_view);
        tab2.setIcon(R.drawable.logo_a);

        TabLayout.Tab tab3 = tabLayout.getTabAt(2);
        tab3.setCustomView(R.layout.icon_view);
        tab3.setIcon(R.drawable.settings);

    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = null;
            switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
                case 1: {
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find, container, false);
                    break;
                }

            }

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            switch (position) {
                case 0: {
                    return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(1);
                }
                case 1: {
                    return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(2);
                }
                case 2: {
                    SettingsFragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                    return fragment;
                }
            }

            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

[image]

**To resolve this error you have to use `PreferenceFragmentCompat`:**

**1.** To use `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, add below line under `dependencies` in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    .........
    ...............
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.1.0'
}
```

**2.** Extend your `SettingsFragment` from `PreferenceFragmentCompat` instead of `PreferenceFragment`.

```
    import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

    .........
    .................

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

    .........
    .................
```

**3.** You must specify `preferenceTheme` in your `theme`:

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    .......
    ...........
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

You can also check [tutorial](https://storiesandroid.wordpress.com/2015/10/06/android-settings-using-preference-fragments/) to learn more about `PreferenceFragmentCompat`.

Hope this will help~

Comment: Getting this error with your code: i.imgur.com/H7zPpHt.png any idea how to fix it?

Comment: you have to add "import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;" in your activity

Comment: I have given a working solution in my updated answer. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thankyou so much it works now. However are you able to explain why `onCreateView` only has the first 2 fragments? - how does it know to exclude the `SettingsFragment`? (using the same code as yours above)

Comment: Actually adapter is used to set fragments on specific positions of viewpager. See the adapter's getItem() method. It returns PlaceholderFragment for first 2 tab(0, 1) and SettingsFragment for 3rd tab(2). That's why PlaceholderFragment's onCreateView() will be called only for first 2 tab and as we return SettingsFragments for 3rd tab, so its onCreatePreferences() will be called when your tab navigates to 3rd tab. Hope you understand the scenario. If my answer seems useful please give an upvote. Thanks in advance :)